# How to import forked library to Angular2

Tags: angular

I've looked so far to find the answer, but found nothing, so exuse me, if my querstion is frequently asked, but I'm too stupid to google it correctly.

I've tried to use JS drag'n'drop library [Draggable](https://github.com/Shopify/draggable), but I need to change some things to use it properly.

So I've forked and downloaded it, but now I have troubles with import it.

- I've tried to import it like module, but it is .js extension of file
  with all imports and exports in it (I tried to change it to .ts, but
  it doesn't help);
- I've tried to import it in index.html in , but it alerts what that file is text/html type so it can't be imported;
- I've tried to interact with npm to create my own package from forked library or something like that, but I'm so lame in npm, so it was no chances.

So I look the way to import this local library so it will be work as imported via npm, but will can do some changes in it.

I'm using Ubuntu Mate 16.04, my Angular2 project app folder looks like that:
app
|
--draggable (folder with library I want to use)
|
other components and standart files

**EDIT:** I've installed library via npm, using path/to/folder (`npm install ./src/app/draggable --save` inside my Angular2 app), so in package.json it is row with name of package and : `"file:src/app/draggable"` after that.

But when I try to use this like `import { Droppable } from '{myName}'`, it is compiling error: `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '{myName}' in '/{pathToProject}/src/app'`

How can I fix this and use the local library?

Answer (score 0):

You can `npm publish` your altered package under another name (name in `package.json`) to `npmjs.org`. To do this you type `npm publish` at the command-line from the packages root directory where the `packagage.json` of your package is. And then you import is like you would do with the original package (and may adjust the name of the package).

Or you can make your changes in the `node_modules` folder (but this is temporary and can be undone when you call `npm install`). So if you choose the second approach you should copy the hole package to another place. This way the import is the same.

Comment: I need to publish this from my github account or what?
Also, when I tried to publish and have an errors, I've seen something like "you can also install from a folder". Is it true?

Comment: No you publish it from your hard-drive. From command-line `cd` in projects roots folder (where package.json is) and just type `npm publish`. Yes, you can put packages directly in your npm-cache, but i don't know how exactly this is working.